# MDX: RANK showing ties, even though data values are different

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx

The original query I had didn't have the [Row Axis] SET which appears below, it worked, but had 'duplicated' ranking values

Someone suggested that I move the row axis, but now instead of 'repeated rank values' I just get #Error showing

What is wrong with my RANK function?

```
WITH 
  SET [Row Axis] AS
  /*NON EMPTY */
    (
      Generate
      (
        [PortfolioBenchmarks]
       ,TopCount
        (
            (
              [Portfolio].[Portfolio Name].CurrentMember
             ,[Portfolio Benchmark].[Benchmark Name].CurrentMember
            )
          * 
            [Factors]
         ,10
         ,Abs([Measures].[FormattedBarraoutput])
        )
      ) 
    )


  SET [Portfolios] AS 
    {
      [Portfolio].[Portfolio Name].&[thingy one]
     ,[Portfolio].[Portfolio Name].&[thingy two]
     ,[Portfolio].[Portfolio Name].&[another thingy]
     ,[Portfolio].[Portfolio Name].&[all these get passed in as params anyhoo]
     ,[Portfolio].[Portfolio Name].&[one more for luck]
    } 
  SET [PortfolioBenchmarks] AS 
    {
      Filter
      (
          [Portfolios]
        * 
          [Portfolio Benchmark].[Benchmark Name].Children
       ,(NOT 
          IsEmpty([Measures].[Barra Relative Result Percentage]))
      )
    } 
  SET [Factors] AS 
    {
        (
          [Barra Scenario].[Barra Scenario Name].&[Eff Active Weight (%)]
         ,[Barra Factor].[Factor Type].&[GICSIndustry]
        )
      * 
        [Barra Factor].[Factor Value].Children
    } 

  MEMBER [Measures].[FormattedBarraoutput] AS 
    IIF
    (
      IsEmpty([Measures].[Barra Relative Result Percentage])
     ,NULL
     ,[Measures].[Barra Relative Result Percentage]
    ) 
   MEMBER [Measures].[Ranking] AS
   RANK  ([Row Axis].CurrentMember,[Portfolios], [Measures].[FormattedBarraoutput])

SELECT 
  {[Measures].[FormattedBarraoutput],[Measures].[Ranking]} ON COLUMNS
 ,[Row Axis] ON ROWS
FROM [wobbly_woo]
WHERE 
  (
    [Time].[TimeKey].&[20120131]
  );
```

---

Comment: Can you provide some data as to the output of the query?  Which data is repeated?  Based on your useage of rank, the only value being considered for duplication would be [Measures].[FormattedBarraoutput]